# Confused by 3 nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I'm working on pulling data from an excel file saved on SharePoint Document Library.  I'm getting the rows and I'm confused at the data structure.  I'm still fairly new to typscript/javascript.

I'm getting the rows back:

```
private _getRows(documentLibraryID: string, documentID: string, worksheet: string, table: string): Promise<[MicrosoftGraph.WorkbookTableRow]> {
  return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
    this.props.context.msGraphClientFactory
    .getClient()
      .then((client: MSGraphClient): void => {
        client
          .api(`/sites/${URL}/drives/${documentLibraryID}/items/${documentID}/workbook/worksheets('${worksheet}')/Tables('${table}')/rows`)
          .get((error, response: any, rawResponse?: any) => {
            if (response) {
              let rows:[MicrosoftGraph.WorkbookTableRow] = response.value;

              resolve(rows);
            }
            else {
              reject(error);
            }
          });
        });
  });
}
```

What I get back:

[image]

I try to enumerate through the arrays:

```
  for (let row of rows) {
    console.log("row: ", row);
    for (let value of row.values) {
      console.log("value: ", value);
      for (let newValue of value.values) {
        console.log("newValue: ", newValue);

      }
    }
  }
```

But I don't get to the `newValue` object:

[image]

What don't I understand about this structure?  It looks like 3 nested arrays.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it

Comment: @JonasWilms I'm sorry, what are you trying to say?  The object I'm trying to use is returned from Microsoft's Graph API, so I have no control over that. Are you saying something about my `_getRows` method and how I am handling the promise?  I'm happy to receive any feedback on my code structuring, i'm pretty new to Typescript/Javascript.

Comment: I guess 3 mins weren't enough to read the answers ...

Comment: @JonasWilms You're right.  I re-read it and I'm still not sure how to improve my promise chaining.

Comment: You should return the `new Promise` from inside the `then`, that way if `.getClient()` rejects it can be handled too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that when you're reaching to this point: `for (let value of row.values)`, `value` is indeed an array. So there's no need of doing `value.values`.

This code should work fine:

```
for (let row of rows) {
    console.log("row: ", row);
    for (let valueArr of row.values) {
      console.log("value: ", valueArr);
      for (let newValue of valueArr) {
        console.log("newValue: ", newValue);

      }
    }
  }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Ha, that was it!  Thank you!